# Using spring @Transactional for the beans created using factory method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-3

I am using spring3. I have below classes.

### Transport.java

```
package com.net.core.ioc;

public interface Transport {
  public void doSave();
}
```

### Car.java

```
package com.net.core.ioc;

    public class Car implements Transport{
     String name;
     public Car(String name){
         this.name=name;
      }
        public void doSave(){
            //saving logic using name
        }
    }
```

### Bus.java

```
package com.net.core.ioc;

    public class Bus implements Transport {
      String id;
      public Bus(String id){
         this.id=id;
      }
        public void doSave() {
            //saving logic using id
        }
```

### SpringService.java

```
package com.net.core.ioc;

    public class ServiceLocator {
        private static ServiceLocator service = new ServiceLocator ();

        //Static factory method
        public static ServiceLocator createService(){
            return service;
        }

        //Instance factory methods
        public Transport createCarInstance(String name){
        return new Car(name);
        }

    public Transport createBusInstance(String id){
            return new Bus(id);
        }

    }
 }
```

### config.xml

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.net.core.ioc"/>
        <bean id="serviceLocator" class="com.net.core.ioc.ServiceLocator"factory-method="createService"/>
        <bean id="springServiceCarInstance" factory-bean="serviceLocator" factory-method="createCarInstance" scope="prototype"/>
        <bean id="springServiceBusInstance" factory-bean="serviceLocator" factory-method="createBusInstance" scope="prototype"/>
    </beans>
```

Now i am getting beans as below:

```
Transport request = (Transport)applicationContext.getBean("springServiceCarInstance","someName");
request.doSave();
```

**Now can i use spring transactions here ? I mean can i annotate Car and Bus classes using @Transactional ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No.  Since car and bus are not created by the spring factory, the instances you get will not be transaction weaved proxies so the annotations would be pointless.

You want to create it via the spring context using initializeBean or createBean.  For more details, look at the java doc on [AutoWireCapableBeanFactory](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/config/AutowireCapableBeanFactory.html).

Alternately you can register Can and Bus with spring context as prototype beans, and just use getBean( "beanName", BeanType.class ) and spring will always return you new instances of them.

```
@Component
@Scope("singleton")
public class CarFactory {

    @Autowired
    private AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory;

    public Car create( Make make, Model model, Year year ) {
        Car car = new Car( make, model, year );

        // this will apply the post processors including ones that might wrap the original bean
        // such as transaction interceptors etc.
        Car carProxy = Car.class.cast(autowireCapableBeanFactory.configureBean(car, "carBean"));
        return carProxy;
    }
}
```

Comment: lscoughlin, Thanks much for your answer. But everytime i call getBean() i need to pass some values to beans constructor. How can i do that?

Comment: By default Spring AOP is proxy based so I see no reason why the code in the question should not work.

Comment: @Boris because he's manually calling constructors and returning raw instances.  He's not passing through a proxy.

Comment: @user3269829 if you use initializeBean -- you construct it first, and then pass the instance through initialize bean and return the result of that call ( not the newed option ) as the returned bean will be a proxy implementing your AOP options.

Answer (score 2):

`Car` and `Bus` are entities in the object model.  Entities are normally not transactional.  Create a repository/service bean capable of persisting these entity types and then make that bean transactional.

This would allow you to remove the `doSave` method which would eliminate the need for these entities to be declared as beans.

```
@Component
public class CarRepository{

    @Transactional
    public void doSave(Car car){

    }
}
```

Comment: Entities are not normally transactional when you buy into the "transaction script" architectural pattern, which is not related to his question.